# Undesired Pause in Azure Speech Service Neural Voice Synthesis for Long Sentences

Tags: text-to-speech, azure-cognitive-services, azure-speech

I attempted to use Azure Speach Service to synthesize long sentences using a Neural Voice having more than 500 characters without seeing a pause in the speech at 500 characters into a given sentence.

I have any number of places in text I need to synthesize (using Neural Voices) that has some very long sentences. (And no, I can't change them, unfortunately.) I've noticed that around 25-28 seconds into the sentence and apparently always at 500 characters into any sentence, the voice synthesizer will pause about as long as the end of a sentence. I can't have a pause like this. I cannot find anywhere in the documentation that talks about a sentence length limit or about any way to avoid that pause. (perhaps using some SSML tag?)

Can anyone provide some guidance on what can be done to avoid these gaps / pauses?

I know it's possible to edit MP3 files generated, but my workflow just isn't suited for doing so. (i.e., 40,000+ MP3 files, any one of which I may need to resynthesize as mispronunciations, etc. are found, and over 1200 of them have these long sentences with gaps in synthesis) I really need to be able to synthesize the sentences into MP3 files without needing to make manual fixes.

For those not familiar with how to synthesize speech from SSML using the Azure Speech Service SDK, the snippet of code I use is below. But again, it makes no difference whether you synthesize the SSML using this code or whether you use the Azure Speech Service portal. The resulting MP3 has the exact same problem.

```cs
        batchClient = new BatchSynthesisClient(host, speechKey);
        var ssmlFileWithoutExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(ssmlFile);
        Console.WriteLine($"  Enqueuing {ssmlFileWithoutExtension} ({ssmlFile})");
        var ssml = File.ReadAllText(ssmlFile);
        var newSynthesisUri = await batchClient.CreateSynthesisAsync(
            voiceName,
            ssmlFileWithoutExtension,
            "enqueued " + DateTime.Now.ToString("M/d/yyyy h:mmtt"),
            ssml,
            true).ConfigureAwait(false);
        var synthesisId = Guid.Parse(newSynthesisUri.Segments.Last());
// Wait for the job to complete using logic to check for completion
          var synthesis = await batchClient.GetSynthesisAsync(synthesisId).ConfigureAwait(false);
          var downloadUrl = synthesis.Outputs.Result;
          using (HttpResponseMessage response = await batchClient.HttpClient.GetAsync(downloadUrl))
          {
            using (Stream streamToReadFrom = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
            {
              using (Stream streamToWriteTo = File.Open(zipFilePath, FileMode.Create))
              {
                await streamToReadFrom.CopyToAsync(streamToWriteTo);
              }
            }
          }
```

Comment: Can you provide your code in the question?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am using Azure speech synthesis and supplying SSML for all synthesis (which I do with the batch interface), but it is easily reproduced in the Speech Studio with neural voices. (I normally use Tony, Jane, or Davis.) Here is sample SSML that demonstrates the problem using a Bible sentence. You'll notice the artificial pause right at 500 characters in. (right before "oil for light")

Comment: <speak xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis" xmlns:mstts="http://www.w3.org/2001/mstts" xmlns:emo="http://www.w3.org/2009/10/emotionml" version="1.0" xml:lang="en-US"><voice name="en-US-TonyNeural">And they brought the tabernacle unto Moses, the tent and all his furniture, his clasps, his boards, his bars, and his pillars, and his sockets, and the covering of rams’ skins dyed red, and the covering of badgers’ skins, and the veil of the covering, the ark of the testimony and the staves thereof, and the mercy seat, the table

Comment: and all the vessels thereof, and the showbread, the pure candlestick with the lamps thereof, even with the lamps to be set in order and all the vessels thereof, and the oil for light, and the golden altar, and the anointing oil, and the sweet incense, and the hanging for the tabernacle door, the brazen altar and his grate of brass, his staves and all his vessels, the basin and his foot, the hangings of the court, his pillars and his sockets, and the hanging for the court gate, his cords and his pins, and all the vessels of the service of the tabernacle, for the tent of the congregation,

Comment: the cloths of service to do service in the holy place, and the holy garments for Aaron the priest, and his sons’ garments to minister in the priest’s office.</voice></speak>

Comment: @VaughnHughes Provide your complete code in proper coding language then only we can conclude your problem and better way to understand it.

Comment: @DasariKamali, I've added code above. Use it with the SSML XML I provided or just use the SSML in the portal. It yields the same problematic result. The code works just fine and is not problematic.

Comment: Hi @DasariKamali. Have you had a chance to conclude my problem and a better way to understand it? Thanks.

Comment: Here's an example of what this particular sentence looks like when synthesized by Azure Speech Service, whether through Speech Studio or whether through my .NET 6 app calling the batch synthesis API. [Screen capture](https://learn-attachment.microsoft.com/api/attachments/23e7a3ad-f261-42e4-8d4f-eda3b09e95a4?platform=QnA)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this is a fundamental limitation of the Azure Speech Service, and it remains undocumented. 500 characters is the maximum sentence length it will synthesize before arbitrarily inserting a significant pause. (about as long as for a period at the end of a sentence) I'm hoping someone at Microsoft will document it, so the next person who comes along doesn't spend months & loads of money on this like I did.